# Bluetooth Problem

Tags: ati, bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10(saucy) in a Dell N5010 notebook. My bluetooth is not detected. How to fix it. 
Also Do I need to install anything for My ATI 512 MB Graphics Card for full utilizatiion of my graphics card features.

Answer (score 0):

Search for software sources in your dash and open the additional drivers tab and install the recommended drivers.

Comment: A more specific reference will be very helpful as my ubuntu pc if void of internet connection. I need to download it with keryx.